# how to remove ParentDirectory in zip file when use java.util.zip

Tags: java, zip

`zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName))`,

Here the fileName is the name that will show inside zip

so I do this to resolve is：

```
zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file3.replace("C:/1/hisenyuan","")));

I want zip folder:C:\1\hisenyuan
```

**Main code：**

```
        String file3 = file2.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
          is = new FileInputStream(file3);
          //here the file3 is the name that will show inside zip
          zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file3.replace("C:/1/hisenyuan","")));
          int temp = 0;
          int bufferSize = 1024 * 5;
          byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
          while ((temp = is.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, temp);
            zos.flush();
          }
```

by my way zip's folder structure is：

```
C:\1\hisenyuan\build.png
C:\1\hisenyuan\DSCN6812.JPG
C:\1\hisenyuan\test\test\hello.zip
C:\1\hisenyuan\test\hisenyuan.zip
C:\1\hisenyuan\test\test.txt
C:\1\hisenyuan\test\test\hello\hello.txt
C:\1\hisenyuan\tomcat.png
```

I want the zip's folder structure is:

```
build.png
DSCN6812.JPG
test\hello.zip
test\hisenyuan.zip
test\test.txt
test\hello\hello.txt
tomcat.png
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little and purpose behind it ?

Comment: zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName)), here the fileName is the name that  show inside zip